# jquery loop breaking without checking if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

```
<script>
    function validatePurchaseForm() {

        if ($.trim($("#datepicker").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#datepicker").text = "";
            $("#datepicker").mouseover();
            $("#datepicker").focus();
            return false;
        } else if ($.trim($("#invoiceNumber").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#invoiceNumber").text = "";
            $("#invoiceNumber").mouseover();
            $("#invoiceNumber").focus();
            return false;
        } else if ($.trim($("#supplier").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#supplier").text = "";
            $("#supplier").mouseover();
            $("#supplier").focus();
            return false;

        }else if(true){

            for(index=0;index<${itemCount};index++){

                if ($("#itemName"+index).length > 0) {
                    if ($("#itemName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#itemName"+index).mouseover();
                            break;
                    }
                } else if ($("#companyName"+index).length > 0) {
                    if ($("#companyName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#companyName"+index).mouseover();
                            break;
                    }
                } else if ($("#type"+index).length > 0) {
                    if ($("#type"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#type"+index).mouseover();
                            break;
                        }
                } else if ($("#partyName"+index).length > 0) {
                    if ($("#partyName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#partyName"+index).mouseover();
                            break;
                        }
                } else if ($("#itemNumber"+index).length > 0) {
                        if ($.trim($("#itemNumber"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                } else if ($("#itemWeight"+index).length > 0) {
                        if ($.trim($("#itemWeight"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                } else if ($("#purchaseDesc"+index).length > 0) {
                        if ($.trim($("#purchaseDesc"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                }   

            }

            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>
```

"itemCount" is set from jstl in the page. All are coming fine, but while the method is called

```
if ($("#itemName"+index).length > 0) {
                    if ($("#itemName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#itemName"+index).mouseover();
                            break;
                    }
```

controls goes inside this first loop eventhough the value is not "NONE" and breaks. Whats gone wrong here?. Kindly check.Am not able to go through. Am triggering mouseover to show tooltip in the page.

Comment: ".text()" is a method, not a property. If you want to set it as "", use: .text("")

Comment: hi Ian, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I corrected it. But the real issue is that though the if condition is false, its executing the break statement inside it. "really confused" :O

Comment: hi friends , got it working. It was conflit with if-else-if ladder and break statements. I will share the code. now since am a new user with less than 10 points, stack overflow is restricting me to answer myown answer with in 8 hrs since the qn was asked. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working. I guess theres was some conflits between the if-else if ladder and break statements. Below is the working code.

```
<script>
    function validatePurchaseForm() {

        if ($.trim($("#datepicker").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#datepicker").val("");
            $("#datepicker").mouseover();
            $("#datepicker").focus();
            return false;
        } else if ($.trim($("#invoiceNumber").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#invoiceNumber").val("");
            $("#invoiceNumber").mouseover();
            $("#invoiceNumber").focus();
            return false;
        } else if ($.trim($("#supplier").val()).length == 0) {

            $("#supplier").val("");
            $("#supplier").mouseover();
            $("#supplier").focus();
            return false;

        }

            for(index=0;index<${itemCount};index++){

                status=true;


                    if ($("#itemName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#itemName"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                    }

                    if ($("#companyName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#companyName"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                    }

                    if ($("#type"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#type"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                        }

                    if ($("#partyName"+index).val() == "NONE") {
                            $("#partyName"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                        }

                    if ($.trim($("#itemNumber"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#itemNumber"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                        }

                    if ($.trim($("#itemWeight"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#itemWeight"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                        }

                    if ($.trim($("#purchaseDesc"+index).val()).length == 0) {
                            $("#purchaseDesc"+index).mouseover();
                            status=false;
                            break;
                        }

            }

        if(!status){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>
```